# Preserve row and column order of data frame when converting data frame to matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, reshape2

I have a dataframe:

```
 df<- data.frame(lep= c("Tarchon", "Tarchon", "Tarchon", "Tarchon", "Tarchon", 
               "Gonodonta","Gonodonta","Gonodonta", "Apatelodes"), 
               plant=c("Amphimoea","Desmotrichia", "Paches", "Neoxeniades",
                       "Desmotrichia","Neoxeniades","Amphimoea", "Acribia","Sychesia"), 
               freq=c(2,5,1,3,4,2,1,1,4))
```

That I convert to a matrix using:

```
mat1<-acast(df, plant~lep, value.var="freq", sum)
```

The output alphabetizes the names of the `plant` and `lep` however I want the order in the data frame to be maintained in the matrix.

Here is the desired output:

```
 mdat <- matrix(c(2,5,1,3,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4), nrow = 6, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
           dimnames = list(c("Amphimoea","Desmotrichia", "Paches", "Neoxeniades",
                             "Acribia","Sychesia"),
                           c("Tarchon","Gonodonta", "Apatelodes")))
```

I am not partial to using `acast` for this, I have just found this function helpful for the type of data frame I have. I am not able to find an argument in `acast` that preserves the order i the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Factors will are sorted by the order of their levels, which is alphabetical by default. You can specify a different order using the `levels` argument of `factor`. `unique` will return the unique values in the order they occur, which we can use here:

```
df$lep = factor(df$lep, levels = unique(df$lep))
df$plant = factor(df$plant, levels = unique(df$plant))

reshape2::acast(df, plant~lep, value.var="freq", sum)
#              Tarchon Gonodonta Apatelodes
# Amphimoea          2         1          0
# Desmotrichia       9         0          0
# Paches             1         0          0
# Neoxeniades        3         2          0
# Acribia            0         1          0
# Sychesia           0         0          4
```